# Calling json from <a>

Tags: 8

in mt .tp file I have a loop that
outputs Publish or something similar for each entry. I don't want it to refresh the page when clicking on the  so I want to call some json instead to call a module and pass some parameters to update the Database but I am not sure how to go about it. Do I need a new module with something like this in it?

```
function menudemo_menu() {

    $menuitems['menudemo'] = array(

    'title' => 'My Menu',

    'page callback' => 'menudemo_mymenu_page_callback',

    'access callback' => TRUE,

    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,

    );

    return $menuitems;

}

function menudemo_mymenu_page_callback() {

    return 'My Menu URL was hit';

}
```

And how do I pass the parameters

Comment: Are you trying to reload some part of your page with an AJAX Callback ?

Comment: I just want to click  on the <a> in <div><a class="button" href="">Publish</a></div> to update the Database and the contents of the div will then change to say it has been done. The div will need an id so the json can write to it

Comment: From what I understand it's a Callback AJAX to publish content without reloading the page. You'll have to either trigger an event in JS to callback your hook_menu that will update the database or user a button and the AJAX Form API => https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#ajax

Comment: Yep it is. Good it sounds as though I am going the right way about it then - thanks

Comment: Here is a nice example: http://phpgainers.com/content/post-data-using-jquery-json-and-ajax-drupal-7-programmatically/

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the confirmation -  I was on the right track. I just need to add in the sql update command now and will all be working.